# C# Oracle database connection

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to connect to an oracle database using C#.

Here is my code:

```
      OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(); // C#
           conn.ConnectionString = oradb;
        conn.Open();
        string sql = " select department_name from departments where department_id = 10"; // C#
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; ///this is the line that gives the error
```

What is the proper way to set the command type?  Thank you.

Comment: How about executing command without specify CommandType? By the way can you reveal more code here?

Comment: Hassan Nisar do you mean where is the cmd.ExecuteDataReader command..?

Comment: Just remove that line.

Comment: here is a good `SO` example to follow I suggest you get familiar with `using` statement and how to wrap your code for disposing automatically as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101786/need-help-with-database-connection-and-query-code also learn how to use `Parameterized querys` I doubt that you will be wanting to hard code your Where Filter

Comment: @DJKRAZE. I expect OP has not posted `cmd.ExecuteReader()` intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Store Procedure**:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection( oradb ))
{
      conn.Open();
      OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("StoreProcedureName", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   

      //specify command parameters 
      //and Direction

      using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
             //string s = reader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + reader.GetInt32(1);
          }
      }                   
}
```

**CommandType.Text**: (not mandatory to specify CommandType).

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection( oradb ))
{
      string sql = @"SELECT department_name FROM departments 
                     WHERE department_id = @department_id";
      conn.Open();
      OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);

      //specify command parameters
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@department_id", 10));

      using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
             //string s = reader.GetString(0);
          }
      }                   
}
```

Comment: Yes @Brett. I intentionally left it out to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you toss each of these pieces in a using() statement, i.e.

```
using( OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection( oradb ) )
{
    conn.Open();

    using( OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand( "sql here", conn ) )
    {
        //cmd.Execute(); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I set the cmd to be Text vs Stored procedure?

Comment: This is a good answer -- the usings are critical here as you will certainly cause a memory leak otherwise (can testify from experience).  The default command type is Text, so you should be all set. See: 

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm#i997757  

I only recall changing the CommandType when I wanted to execute a stored procedure.

Comment: @Brett when you want to do a stored procedure do you do it like Hassan's answer  or some other way?

Comment: Hassan's answer is more complete, and, yes, that's what I would do.